# How to target thumbnails of the first post in the loop

Tags: loop

ok currently my last post's thumbnail have an extra class, which were added by this code:

```
<?php $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';?>
```

but now I want to target the thumbnail of the first post, not last. how can I do it?

full code(after editing upon Robert's reference):

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'asc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $extraFirstClass = $loop->current_post == '0' ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : ''; ?>

<?php 
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraFirstClass,
    "id" => "photo_{$post->ID}",
);
the_post_thumbnail("portfolio_thumb", $attributes);
?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php rewind_posts(); ?> 


    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get first post class similarly as you are adding last post class.

In last post case, you were checking if `current_post` number is equal to `post_count`. But in this case when we want to get first post, we will check if `current_post` number in loop is equal to 0 or not.

```
<?php $extraFirstClass = $loop->current_post == '0' ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : ''; ?>
```

Comment: not working for me. :(

Comment: Try again. I added extra char in equal sign. It would be working now.

Comment: it works, but after I hover once. the full code is added to the main post, can you check?
actually I'm trying to make something like this:
http://kzarchitecture.com/portfolio/

Comment: I have no idea how this section is working. It mostly looks like JavaScript work. This question was about targeting first thumb, which I answered already. If you need further help, create another question with detailed information of what exactly do you want. You should not simply edit/extend question if the solution you thought is not working.

Comment: Also, if the hover effect is not working properly then it's some issue in JavaScript. WordPress is only producing required HTML, and dynamic part is JavaScript's responsibility.

Comment: no, the hover effect is working fine. but the issue is last thumbnail is loading first. your code does work, but I have to hover at least once.

actually the code from I'm copying (if you visit here: http://kzarchitecture.com/portfolio/) the are printing the first thumbnail twice, at start & at ending & added the "main-image-porfolio-main" to the ending part. my code doesn't have this, I'm printing the image only once.